# Opencart issue with response cookies when add to cart button is clicked

Tags: cookies, opencart, setcookie

**Opencart**: v.1.5.6
**Languages**: en (English), el (Greek)
**Default language**: el (Greek)
**vQmods**: A lot
**Modules**: A lot

On my category lists of products & in product's page, when I click on **Add to Cart** I get a `Response Cookies` > `language: el` although I am in the **english** version of the e-shop. Have a look at the image

[image: Opencart issue with response cookies when add to cart button is clicked]

That response cookie messes up the (language) content of **mini-cart**.

Could someone explain what's that response cookie?
Could someone point out what kind of modification should I look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I deleted all the .xml files in `/vqmod/xml/` except from `vqmod_opencart.xml`.
2. I added one by one the deleted .xml files and test the e-Shop.
3. I have found that `/vqmod/xml/seo_mega_pack.xml` (**SEO Mega KIT**) was causing all this mess.

**Solution**:
Inside Opencart's dashboard go to...

> Dashboard > Modules > SEO Mega KIT PLUS > Settings > Language >
>   (**uncheck**) Change the language to the default after opening the
>   main URL